# Expected Time to fill the bucket with M drops for the first time?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We are given an empty bucket. Following events occur every second.

- $1$ drop increases in the bucket with probability $A$ = $1/6$.
- $1$ drop decreases in the bucket with probability $B$ = $1/8$.
- Nothing happens

What is the expected time when the bucket would fill with $M$ drops for the first time (Event B cannot happen if the bucket is empty)?

---

My Approach: For an empty bucket, I have two possibilities :

- 1 drop increase with the probability A.
- Nothing happens.

So, to fill the bucket with $1$st drop for the first time: $1*A + 2*(1-A)*A + 3*(1-A)*(1-A)*A.............$ = $1/A$ = 6 seconds.

How can I proceed further ?

Comment: What if it's empty and event $B$ happens?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel That is not possible. I missed it. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_i$ be the expected time for $M$ drops to be reached from a state with $i$ drops. Then the answer is $E_0$ in the solution to the square tridiagonal linear system
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1/6&-1/6\\
-1/8&7/24&-1/6\\
&&\ddots\\
&&-1/8&7/24&-1/6\\
&&&-1/8&7/24\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}E_0\\E_1\\\vdots\\E_{M-1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
For $M=1,2,\dots$ the expected times are
$$6,\frac{33}2,\frac{243}8,\frac{1497}{32},\frac{8331}{128},\frac{43425}{512},\dots$$
For a generalised version with probabilities $A$ and $B$ of gaining and losing a drop respectively, empirical tests give the expected time to hit $M$ drops as
$$\frac1A\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}(M-k)\left(\frac BA\right)^k=\begin{cases}\frac B{(A-B)^2}\left(\left(\frac BA\right)^M-1\right)+\frac M{A-B}&A\ne B\\\frac{M(1+M)}{2A}&A=B\end{cases}$$
For the parameters in the given problem, the formula is therefore $24(3((3/4)^M-1)+M)$.

Comment: Can you a bit elaborate the first matrix ?

Comment: @JonGarrick Write down the equations for exepcted value for each state and simplify. So if there is $1$ drop, there is a $1/6$ chance of moving to $2$, $1/8$ to $0$ and hence $17/24$ to $1$ - after one second has passed of course.

Comment: Thanks I am able to get it now. One more clarity I need is how you got 7/24 ?

Comment: @JonGarrick $\frac7{24}=\frac16+\frac18$. The equation for $E_1$ reads $E_1=\frac16E_2+\frac18E_0+(1-1/6-1/8)E_1$ - everything simplifies from there.